# Change Navigation Bar background UIColor

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to change my navigation bar colour and I do it with this famous command:

```
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:57/255.0 green:50/255.0 blue:36/255.0 alpha:0];
```

(or alpha:1)

The problem is that the Color appears as graduate (white on the top edge, dark on the button)- how can i get rid of this "effect" and make my colour uniform

Answer (score 0):

To remove the gradient you need to subclass `UINavigationBar` and implement `drawRect:` to draw your chosen colour.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to subclass, you could always just make a 1x1 image in the color you want and set it as the bar's background image:

```
UIImage *image = [self imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

[Source for imageWithColor:](https://gist.github.com/kevinmcmahon/2295471)